# Image enlarge transition

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML and CSS but I've strung together some code that makes my images enlarge a little bit when my mouse hovers over them. However, the images sometimes don't enlarge over each other, some stay behind others because they are positioned closely together. Does anyone know how to make them ignore the other images when they enlarge?

Here's my code:

```
img.one {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
```

}

```
img.one:hover {
transform: scale(1.1);
```

}

Comment: I understand that the class _one_ only affects to one image, right? Can you provide us an example of your code? Using code snippet right here, or at jsfiddle?

Comment: @anfuca sorry I don't know how to do that, but the guy below's suggestion works! I'm going to upvote it when I can.

Comment: @Henry Thanks! I believe you can mark my answer as the solution (with the checkmark icon) to help others, even if you can't upvote yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `z-index` property to control which elements are in front of others.

```
img.one:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 1;
}
```